# Как вывести значение по ключу в словаре \\ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, вывод, словарь

Использую JSON, нужно вывести значение из словаря по ключю.

Например {"keys":"value"}

jsonStr = json.loads(mydict, ensure_ascii=False,)
mydict - словарь

Нужно, вывести value.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы словарь не сбрасывался при выключении кода? PYTHON](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-python)

Answer (score 1):

вам это нужно?

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"keys":"value"}')

print(data['keys'])
```

Comment: у меня json.dumps()

Comment: jsonStr = json.loads(mydict, ensure_ascii=False,)

Comment: тогда в сем проблема именно?

Comment: [1](https://sun9-36.userapi.com/impg/CJqE7I7lrxDL-QKhP9k1VrqFMeM856MAkX_SOA/afn4350e4Rk.jpg?size=377x86&quality=96&sign=b9b5ab9625ad794ab4af830699c1a5ba&type=album)

Comment: эта ошибка выходит, если запустить код: `jsonStr[keys]`

Comment: @Darksnaper что Вам мешает скопировать текст ошибки и Ваш код?

Comment: с чего Вы решили, что в str должны быть ключи?! str это не dict, как в Вашем вопросе!

Comment: А как не переводить в строку, а оставить словарь?

Comment: А зачем вообще переводить в строку?

Comment: Я не переводил, я прописал этот код 

 `jsonStr = json.dumps(mydict, ensure_ascii=False,)`

mydict - это словарь 
,но jsonStr - строка, можно как-то сделать jsonStr словарём?

Comment: @Darksnaper Ну у вас же mydict - и есть словарь. А вы его переводите в строчку. Если вам нужен словарь, а не его сериализованное строковое представление, то просто оставьте его как есть. Зачем вы вообще делаете json.dumps, если вам это не нужно?

Comment: при выключение кода, словарь сбрасывается, а мне нужно, что содержимое в нём оставалось